# Why does rust WASM build with shared memory support needs more memory?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I've written smallest rust WASM app I could

```
#![no_std]
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::wasm_bindgen;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn run() {
}
```

Its WASM file size is 27063 bytes.
And yet it fails with

> Uncaught (in promise)
> LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): memory import 26 is smaller than initial 18, got 17" when WebAssembly.Memory called with initial less than 18 and maximum less than 19.

19 x 65536 is way bigger than the WASM size.

this was compiled with

```
"build:wasm": "rustup run nightly wasm-pack build .. --target web --out-dir pkg -- -Z build-std=panic_abort,std",
```

and

```
[target.wasm32-unknown-unknown]
rustflags = [
    "--cfg=web_sys_unstable_apis",
    "-C", "target-feature=+atomics,+bulk-memory,+mutable-globals",
    "-C", "link-args=--shared-memory",
]

[unstable]
build-std = ["panic_abort", "std"]
```

js part is trivial -

```
 const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 18,
        maximum: 19,
        shared: true
    });
```

when compiled without those flags it runs fine with initial/maximum set to 1.
So the question now is why rust wasm compiled with shared-memory requires so much more memory? It should be just few more bytes of libs added?

the wasm2wat output on wasm built with shared memory was:

> 000040e: error: memory may not be shared: threads not allowed

running it on 'normal' wasm file produces losts of output including

> (memory (;0;) 17)
> (export "memory" (memory 0))

Comment: The wasm file size and memory size are unrelated. You'll probably have to show us what other code you have (whatever JS you wrote to instantiate the wasm, and any compiler flags like `-Clink-arg=--initial-memory=` or `-Clink-arg=--import-memory`). Also maybe paste the output of `wasm2wat your.wasm | grep memory`.

Comment: yep, you're right, it seems to be because of link-args=--shared-memory, but I'm still puzzled why it is so. Can't find any solid reading on the subject. Google brings only sparse comments in the github threads

Comment: I can't reproduce the `--shared-memory` changing anything about the memory size. I can, however, change the initial memory size with `-Clink-arg=-zstack-size=65536`. I suppose this means that rust keeps the addressable/non-shadow part of the stack in the first 1MB of wasm memory by default. (Not sure whether it places stack or static memory first.) (Also, I guess you needed `wasm2wat --threads` or `wasm-dis`, but with the info you posted, I was at least able to reproduce your wasm binary and poke around.)

Comment: looks like all the magic is in https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/main/crates/threads-xform/src/lib.rs#L34: 

// Now we need to allocate extra static memory for:
        // - A thread id counter.
        // - A temporary stack for calls to `malloc()` and `free()`.
        // - A lock to synchronize usage of the above stack.
        // For this, we allocate 1 extra page of memory (should be enough as temporary
        // stack) and grab the first 2 _aligned_ i32 words to use as counter and lock.